# time depending value calculation

Tags: r

Hy guys,
I have several data frames, each one of them made up by 2 columns:

```
Date                   Value1
2013-07-03 16:05:00     1178
2013-07-03 16:10:00     1200
2013-07-03 16:15:00     1180
2013-07-03 16:20:00     1175
2013-07-03 16:25:00     1205
2013-07-03 16:30:00     1170
.....
```

In other word I have a measure of Value1 every five minutes (for a whole month). What I tried (without results) is to create a new df with two columns, with the mean for every hour of Value1. Result should be like:

```
Date                   Value1
2013-07-03 16:00:00     1180
2013-07-03 17:00:00     1210
.....
```

Where 1178 is the mean of Value1 for the period from 16:00 to 17:00 and so one..
I formatted the column Date as date with

```
df$Date<-as.POSIXct(df$Date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "")
```

Is there a quick way to do that?

I also tried to use the zoo package:

```
zoo_df<-read.zoo(df, header=T, tz="GMT")
aggregate(zoo_df, as.Date, mean)
```

Obviously the function as.Date works perfectly for a daily mean, isn't there a similar way to do the same for an hourly mean?

Comment: does this work? hour=floor(as.double(df$Date)/3600) ttapply(df$Value1, hour, mean)

Comment: I receive an error: Error in tapply(df$Value1, hour, mean) : object "hour" not found

Answer (score 4):

Use the time series packages:

```
DF <- data.frame(Date=seq(from=as.POSIXct("2013-07-03 16:05:00", tz="GMT"),
                          to=as.POSIXct("2013-07-04 16:05:00", tz="GMT"),
                          by="5 min"),
                 Value1=1:289)

library(xts)
myTS <- zoo(DF[,2], DF[,1])

ep <- endpoints(myTS, "hours")
period.apply(myTS, INDEX=ep, FUN=mean)
```